# Run Python Gtk3 Dialog or message dialog without no transient parent warning

Tags: python, modal-dialog, gtk3

I use Python 2.7 and Gtk3 and every time I launch a Gtk.Dialog I get the warning:

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

I read this is because the dialog needs a parent window - until I call it with **Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL**.

But how?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Question():
    def __init__(self):
        self.message_dialog = Gtk.Dialog(
            "Dialog Title",
            None,
            Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
            )
        self.message_dialog.set_modal(1)
        response = self.message_dialog.run()
        self.message_dialog.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Question()
```

### #

Why not set parent to Gtk.Window() so it runs without warning?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Question():
    def __init__(self):
        self.message_dialog = Gtk.Dialog(
            "Dialog Title",
            Gtk.Window(),
            None,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
            )
        response = self.message_dialog.run()
        self.message_dialog.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Question()
```

Comment: you should edit your question and add the answer as part of your question.

Comment: You should never use a Gtk Dialog as a standalone window. If this is done in the wrong way, it can freeze the desktop. There are a lot of factors involved, like distribution, window manager, and window manager decorations/settings and how you create your dialog. If you need a standalone window, try using a [Gtk Window](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html). There is a very good reason you are getting the warning. Please listen to it and make Gtk a nice toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is just a warning. The main goal of dialogs is to refer to an already existing UI Window, nevertheless, you can create a dialog without a parent as indicated on the [API reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-new-with-buttons), not recommended but possible:

> ...and transient parent parent (or NULL for none...

The advantage is that if you set it then you can set if it's modal or not (possible to do it afterwards too). With modal meaning:

> A “modal” dialog (that is, one which freezes the rest of the
>   application from user input), can be created by calling
>   gtk_window_set_modal() on the dialog...

If the dialog is not modal, then you can interact with the parent which sometimes ain't a good thing due to eventual inconsistencies.

Conclusion: if you **really** need it that way, go ahead, it's just a warning, and don't mind to hide it, or silence it, with a Gtk.Window.

**EDIT (to theGtkNerd comment)**:

The message is indeed a warning, not a compile warning or error but a run-time message. To test it i've done a simple c program and compiled it with Gtk+ version 2 and 3. The result is:

```
[...]$ gcc -o dialog dialog.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
[...]$ ./dialog 

[...]$ gcc -o dialog dialog.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
[...]$ ./dialog 
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

This message was introduced in Gtk+ 3, not sure which minor version number.

Plus, the documentation is very precise on that. Let's check [GtkMessageDialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMessageDialog.html#gtk-message-dialog-new) which inherits from GtkDialog:

[image]

> `parent   transient parent, or NULL for none. [allow-none]`

This being said and as i and theGtkNerd pointed out, it's not recommended to use a GtkDialog without a parent for several reasons but as concluded, if you **REALLY** need it, then go ahead but mind the risks.

Comment: Sorry to disagree with you, but it is more than a warning. See my comment on the original question.

Comment: @theGtknerd No problem :) to disagree is a basic right of freedom :) And your comment is essentially my answer. I'll edit with more details to confirm my answer.